# How to open File related to the error in a View

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt

I am developing a eclipse plugin. In this we are giving a option to user that they can check error in their project.

When user run this plugin I am creating a `View` using `createPartControl()` method to create view like console to display the output.

```
TreeItem item = new TreeItem(tree, SWT.NONE);
item.setText("This is error");

TreeItem subItem = new TreeItem(item, SWT.NONE);
subItem.setText("FIle name");
```

In this view we have some error related to his project with all required details like file name, Line number.

Now i want that when user click on any one of that error, related file should be open in eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a mouse double click listener on your every `TableItem`
which will open the file.

You have to use `IFile` object for it as it's having all the APIs related to it.

```
IPath location = new Path(name);
IFile file = project.getFile(location);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have an `IFile` for the selected file in your view part you can do:

```
IFile file = get file from selection

IWorkbenchPage page = getSite().getPage();

IDE.openEditor(page, file, true);
```

`IDE` is `org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE`.